# Новый проект после загрузки решения на github не отображается

Tags: git, github, commit

Всем привет, вот только начал использовать гитхаб, разбираюсь с коммитами, возникла некая проблемка.

Создал новое решение, добавил в него проект, создал коммит, загрузил на гитхаб. После чего добавил второй проект в это же решение, повторил действия. Изменения были замечены гитом, но на гитхаб не загрузились файлы второго проекта, в чём может быть проблема? Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Возможно вы забыли команду git push?

Answer (score 0):

Нужно было добавить файлы нового проекта через команду
git add